# CodeIgniter 4: How to protect .env from public view?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have configured the database credentials in the .env file. But I can access the file .env file from the browser and it displays all the variables in the .env file.

How do I make it secure so it is not publicly readable?

My folder structure is like this:

```
 public_html/project/ 
                    .env
                    app
                    public
                    system
                    writable
```

The application is accessed from domain.com/project/public.

Comment: is your environment file in your public folder?  Sounds like you have setup issue.  Is your http server such as Apache, nginx, ISS pointing to the root directory of codeigniter?  or to your public directory?

Comment: One thing I see is when people see the public folder - they remove it and do bad things. All you need to do is put the public files into your public_html folder or what ever is your "public" document root with all the other files/folders below that folder. As per the documentation.

Comment: Updated the question with my folder structure.

Comment: @arunkumar Your public folder is meant to be the "public" folder so you should set your document root  to public so that domain.com/project is accessing the public folder. Or if you wish you can rename public to public_html as on a live server ( or whatever the document root is on your hosting )

Answer (score 2):

In fact you're not installing the project correctly on your server

The **public_html** folder should contain files that are intended to be accessible by the browser

In the case of CodeIgniter 4, the contents of the **public_html** folder are the contents of **public** folder, you usually put the front controller **index.php** and your assets folder inside **public_html**

The rest of folders and files goes next to **public_html**, so your folder structure needs to look like this:

```
|__.env
|__app
|__public_html
|____index.php
|____assets
|__system
|__writable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent it from .htaccess

```
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```